# Android toggleButton.setOnText and .invalidate doesn't refresh text

Tags: android, view, refresh, invalidation, android-togglebutton

I have a method like this:

```
ToggleButton toggle = ((ToggleButton)findViewById(R.id.toggle));
toggle.setTextOn("blah");
toggle.setTextOff("blahblah");
toggle.invalidate(); // doesn't work?
```

This methods gets called from `onOptionsItemSelected`. The toggle button is inside a `LinearLayout` which is inside another `LinearLayout`.

I'm expecting the text to update as soon as the method is called. Rather the text on the toggle only updates after I manually press it to switch states. What am I missing here, am I using the wrong method? Why doesn't `.invalidate` work?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Instead of invalidating, you can update the button like this:

```
toggle.setChecked(toggle.isChecked());
```

**Update:**

It is weird that `setTextOff` and `setTextOn` don't update the button. However `setText` does that. So just set the text for each button states and `setText` to update current value:

```
// Text based on state
ToggleButton toggle = ((ToggleButton)findViewById(R.id.toggle));
toggle.setTextOn("blah");
toggle.setTextOff("blahblah");

CharSequence text = toggle.isChecked() ? toggle.getTextOn() : toggle.getTextOff();
toggle.setText(text);
```

Comment: This works, but why? And is this really the best way to do it?

Comment: the solutions feel very hacky but they work. Thanks!

Comment: help, neither of those work for me! the text is setted but the toggle is not updated!!